# BASH comparing Linux version to number?

Tags: bash, compare

I'm trying to work out how to compare the current openSuSE version number to a preset value.

I've got the current version of the installed OS in `$VERSION_ID`

I'm now trying to work out how to compare that to '42.3'. So if the value isn't greater than or equal to quit.

```
if [ ! "$VERSION_ID" -ge 42.3 ]; then
    echo "Sorry Bye";
fi
```

I'm getting:
`[: 42.3: integer expression expected`  But I don't know how to fix that

Any advise please
Thanks

Comment: In general, version numbers aren't floating-point values; they are `.`-delimited sequences of integers. For instance, `42.10` is almost certainly a newer version than `42.9`.

Comment: @chepner Good point, that dupe would solve the Y part of the XY problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version numbers aren't floating point values; they are `.`-delimited sequences of integers. `42.27` is newer than `42.3`, and `42.2.9` could be a valid version number.

Split the version number into its integer components, and compare them "lexiconumerically":

```
target=(42 3)
IFS=. read -a v_id <<< "$VERSION_ID"

for ((i=0; i <${#v_id[@]}; i++)); do
  if (( ${v_id[i]} == ${target[i]} )); then
    continue
  fi

  if (( ${v_id[i]} < ${target[i]} )); then
    echo "version < target"
  elif (( ${v_id[i]} > ${target[i]} )); then
    echo "version > target"
  fi
  break
done
```

Comment: You can use `v_id[i]` and `target[i]` for arrays in arithmetic context, by the way.

Comment: I usually prefer `${...}` in arithmetic expressions, as a guard against undefined variables (the variable alone will default to 0, but the empty string from an expansion produces a syntax error).

Comment: Good point, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a calculator `bc`:

```
if [ $(echo "$VERSION_ID<=42.3" |bc -l) -eq "1" ]; then 
    echo "Sorry Bye";
fi
```

Comment: @Michael O. Thanks this seens to do what I need :)

Comment: Slight change so 42.3 and above is allowed: `if [ `echo $VERSION_ID'<'42.3 | bc -l` != 0 ]; then `